# Amazon device farm - wheel file from macosx platform not supported

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, aws-device-farm, python-appium

I am facing the following error on configuring Appium python test in AWS device farm:

> There was a problem processing your file. We found at least one wheel file wheelhouse/numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl specified a platform that we do not support. Please unzip your test package and then open the wheelhouse directory, verify that names of wheel files end with -any.whl or -linux_x86_64.whl, and try again

I require numpy and opencv-python packages to run my tests.
How to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) is numpy wheel for ubuntu.
 But still Amazon device farm throws error while configuring tests with this wheel.

Basically, Device farm is validating if the .whl file has prefix  **-none-any.whl**

Just renaming the file to **numpy-1.12.0-cp27-none-any.whl** works in device farm.

Note: This renamed file is non-universal python wheel. There might be few things which are not implemented in non-universal python wheel. This may cause somethings to break. So, test to ensure all your dependencies are working fine before using this.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Device Farm has published [packaging requirements for Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html) tests. Specifically, the following appears to apply to you:

> The instructions below are based on Linux x86_64 and Mac. In the
>   currently supported scheme, Device Farm requires that the packaging of
>   your Appium Python tests be done on Linux x86_64 if your tests contain
>   non-universal Python wheels dependencies. For the platform on which
>   you execute a command, the wheels tools gather your .whl dependent
>   files under the wheelhouse/ folder. When you execute the Python wheel
>   command on any platform other than Linux x86_64, you would gather the
>   flavor of a non-univesral wheel dependency for that particular
>   platform and may cause undesired effects. This would most likely lead
>   to errors when executing your tests on Device Farm.

Comment: Numpy in mac machine has macosx_10_10_x86.64.whl
(numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl)

Numpy in linux machine  has manylinux1_x86_64.whl
(numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl)

Both throws error in AWS device farm!

Which means this python package cannot be used in AWS device farm?

Comment: The tests in AWS Device Farm run on an Ubuntu host. If there is a numpy wheel for Ubuntu, then it will work in Device Farm.

Comment: (numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) is numpy wheel for ubuntu.